# Meaning/Usage/Translation: 耳膜 vs. 鼓膜?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

What's the difference between: 耳膜 and 鼓膜?

Apparently they both check out to eardrum in English.

汉语大辞典, even, defines 耳膜 as

> 耳中鼓膜。

Can 鼓膜 be used in other places then?

Comment: no, 鼓膜 is just means eardrum, doesn't have other meanings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary takes extra caution and says it's the membrane in the ear, because 鼓膜 literally means "drum membrane", which might be taken by someone as the membrane on a real drum.

In real usage, however, 鼓膜 is just the eardrum. The membrane on a drum instrument, or the drum head, is called 鼓皮.

Comment: Any examples/excerpts/quotes/etc?

Comment: @user3306356  You can find lots of examples by searching 鼓皮 and 鼓膜 on line.

Answer (score 4):

耳膜and 鼓膜 refer to same thing.
膜，membrane。耳膜，get its name from the position of it. 鼓膜，get its name from its way of working--like the leather cover of a drum.
《高级汉语词典》：耳膜：鼓膜。
and translation to
耳膜：eardrum；
鼓膜: tympanic membrane.

Answer (score 0):

鼓膜 is a medical terms, translated from Western world. It is seldom said in casual conversation.  Say 耳膜 instead.